# Is there an upper bound on signals ascending from the sensory nerves through the medulla?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, perception, neuroanatomy, sensation, awareness

I'm starting to go down a research path related to haptic and embodied cognition. Though I haven't taken a deep dive into neuroanatomy (only a 300 level undergrad cognitive neuroscience course's worth and a good amount of self study), it seems pretty apparent the complexity of the of the mechanoreceptors is greater than that of the fibers ascending the spinal tracts up through the medulla.

Since the sensory nerves bifurcate into seemingly more (please correct me if I'm wrong) nerve endings than the bundles of fibers they send signals up through, I wonder: is there a limit to the amount of somatosensory percepts someone can be aware of at one time?

I thought about looking in the literature for things like, why someone might go into shock when jumping into ice-cold water. Hopefully asking here could bring me closer to an answer or at least a direction to look into.

Thanks,

Holly